# Execute any Raw SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql

IS it possible to execute a raw SQL command of any type (SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE....) in C#.  I am looking to add a feature similar to the SQL Server Management Studio query window where I can just type in any SQL command and it executes it.  In my case I am not worried about sql injection, I know this risk with this feature.  All the connection parameters are passed to me (I have a valid connection string), but I know nothing about the database itself.  The SQL command is also syntactically correct before I get the command.  I cannot seem to find a solution that will work in all cases, probably just overlooking the obvious solution.

Comment: Of course it's possible.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I suggest to use dapper for it: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use ADO .NET and show the results of the query if it executed successfully or not, just put the following code in the event handler when you want to execute your query:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = ConnectionClass.GetInstance().Connection())
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(TextBoxQuery.Text, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    TextBoxNoOfRowEffected.Text = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
}
```

[SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I don't want the results, I just want to run the query.  I will not pass any results back.  This is more for Update, Delete, and Add conditions.  I don't think there will be any Select statements passed to me.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an ADO example for you

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

class Program
{
static void Main()
{
    string connectionString =
        "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Northwind;"
        + "Integrated Security=true";

    // Provide the query string with a parameter placeholder. 
    string queryString =
        "UPDATE [dbo].[USR_Users] SET [Active] = 1 WHERE Id = 1";


    using (SqlConnection connection =
        new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);


        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this work even if the user does a select statement?  I mean I really just want the to use a query string without having to add the parameters.  I am being passed something like this: UPDATE [dbo].[USR_Users] SET [Active] = 1  WHERE Id = 1

Comment: +Syed Farjad Zia Zaidi, +Gary Walker, this example from microsoft website and provided as an example only and not production ready code. However I do agree that since sqlcommand implements IDisposible interface it can be used as a part of using statement, but that's really beyond the original question